# Error Division by Zero in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

Hy Experts, I am new here, I am getting problem with my Excel VBA Code that is use to extract the data over the website. I have two sheets with name as "Input" & "Output" that looks like this....

[Iputsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go0HO.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXfKw.png)

The first sheet will get a url as an input and than run the code written below...

```
  Sub extractTablesData()
Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim str, e As String
Dim pgf, pgt, pg As Integer
Dim ele, Results As Object
Dim add, size, cno, price, inurl, sp, sp1 As String
Dim isheet, rts As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


Set isheet = Worksheets("InputSheet")
Set rts = Worksheets("Results")

url = isheet.Cells(3, 2)

RowCount = 1
    rts.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Address"
    rts.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Size"
    rts.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Contact Number"
    rts.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Price"
    rts.Range("E" & RowCount) = "Url"
LastRow = rts.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  'RowCount = LastRow

 With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (url)

DoEvents
Do While IE.busy Or IE.readystate <> 4
Loop

'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)

For Each Results In .Document.all
    Select Case Results.className
        Case "title search-title"
            str = Results.innerText
            str1 = Split(str, " ")
            str = CInt(str1(0))
 End Select
    If Results.className = "btn btn-main-inverted dropdown-toggle" And InStr(1, Results.Title, " page") > 2 Then
        str2 = Results.Title
        str1 = Split(str2, " ")
        str2 = CInt(str1(0))
    End If
Next
pgno = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(str / str2, 0)

End With
IE.Quit

Set IE = Nothing




UrlS = Split(url, "?")
Url1 = UrlS(0)
Url2 = "?" & UrlS(1)

For i = 1 To pgno
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
url = Url1 & "/" & i & Url2
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (url)

DoEvents
Do While IE.busy Or IE.readystate <> 4
Loop

'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:08 AM#)
For Each ele In .Document.all


    Select Case ele.className
        Case "listing-img-a"
            inurl = ele.href
            rts.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5) = inurl

        Case "listing-location"
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            add = ele.innerText
            rts.Cells(LastRow, 1) = add

        Case "lst-sizes"
            sp = Split(ele.innerText, " ·")

            size = sp(0)
            rts.Cells(LastRow, 2) = size

        Case "pgicon pgicon-phone js-agent-phone-number"      ' btn-tools" 'pgicon pgicon-phone js-agent-phone-number" 'agent-phone-number"
            rts.Cells(LastRow, 3) = ele.innerText

        Case "listing-price"
            price = ele.innerText
            rts.Cells(LastRow, 4) = price



End Select

Next
LastRow = rts.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
rts.Activate
rts.Range("A" & LastRow).Select

End With
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:04 AM#)
Next i






MsgBox "Success"


End Sub
```

after execution of this code  I am getting this error....

[Error Message after code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zJ5p.png)

after debugging I am getting this field as highlighted.... 
[Debug Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trziy.png)

Please check and make me the correction where I am getting error... This code will extract the data after successful running, and at the end it will run the message box with message as "Success"...

Comment: So str2 is = 0. You need to handle this.

Comment: Can you share test URLs?

Comment: https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-sale?limit=30&market=residential&property_type_code%5B%5D=4S&property_type=H&freetext=Yishun

Comment: tbh, I don't know why you don't get a type mismatch since you assign str2 to some text that includes *page* and then try to divide bt that text.

Comment: I am not sure what to advise. There are lots of errors. I have fixed them so that for the test case  given the whole things at least runs until it exits due to pgno being a divide by zero error. I suggest you have a look at the changes. Let me know when you have seen and then I will delete my answer.

Comment: I have give an answer that shows  you a slightly more robust selection. I have left the general comments on your code at the bottom.

Comment: Can I shout `Option Explicit`?

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the actual info off the page efficiently:

You could try the following method which uses CSS selectors.

The `"."` means class and `" a"` means `a` tags within preceeding parent element.

Example: So CSS pattern `.listing-info a` would be `a` tags within parent element(s) having `class = listing-info`.

`querySelectorAll` will find all matching elements having this CSS pattern and return a `nodeList`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetListings()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-sale?limit=30&market=residential&property_type_code%5B%5D=4S&property_type=H&freetext=Yishun", False
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim addresses As Object, address As Object, sizes As Object, prices As Object, _
        listingIds As Object, i As Long, urls As Object

        With .document
            Set addresses = .querySelectorAll(".listing-location")
            Set listingIds = .querySelectorAll(".listing-item")
            Set sizes = .querySelectorAll(".lst-sizes")
            Set prices = .querySelectorAll(".price")
            Set urls = .querySelectorAll(".listing-info a")
        End With
        Dim headers()
        headers = Array("Address", "Size", "ListingId", "Price", "Url")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            For i = 0 To addresses.Length - 1
                .Cells(i + 2, 1) = addresses.item(i).innerText
                .Cells(i + 2, 2) = Split(sizes.item(i).innerText, "S$")(0)
                .Cells(i + 2, 3) = Split(Split(listingIds.item(i).outerHTML, "listing-id-")(1), Chr$(32))(0)
                .Cells(i + 2, 4) = "S$" & prices.item(i).innerText
                .Cells(i + 2, 5) = "https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/" & urls.item(i).getAttribute("href")
            Next i
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

### Getting the number of pages:

You could use a function to get the number of pages in a more reliable way. You can then amend the code above to loop from 1 to pgno very easily.

```
Sub Main
     Dim pgno As Long
    'your other code
    pgno  = GetNumberOfPages(.document)
    'other code
End Sub

Public Function GetNumberOfPages(ByVal doc As HTMLDocument) As Long
    On Error GoTo errhand:
    GetNumberOfPages = doc.querySelector(".listing-pagination li:nth-last-child(2)").innerText
    Exit Function
errhand:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then GetNumberOfPages = 1
End Function
```

---

### Notes on your code from my original non-answer:

I would go with what I have written above and amend into a loop but here are my observations on your code:

0) Main division by 0 error

You need to handle the divide  by zero error of `str2 = 0`. For example:

You could declare `pgno`  as `Variant` and have

```
If str2 = 0 Then 
    pgNo = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
Else 
    pgno = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(str / str2, 0)
End If
```

1) Also, note that when you have multiple declarations on the same line and only declare the type of one, then all the undeclared types implicitly are variant.

E.g.

```
Dim add, size, cno, price, inurl, sp, sp1 As String
```

Only `sp1` is a String. Everthing else is a variant.

If all strings then declare as:

```
Dim add As String, size As String, cno As String, price As String, inurl As String,  sp1 As String
```

I exclude `sp As String` because I think it should be `sp() As String`.

And as `add` and `size` are methods in VBA, I would avoid using them as variable names, and go with `iAdd` or `iSize`, or something more descriptive and useful that cannot be considered ambiguous.

2) You also do not have to use hungarian/pseudo-hungarian notation e.g. `str`.

3) Use `Integer` not `Long`

4) Use `Option Explicit` and check you datatypes. For example, as mentioned in comments, did you mean for str1 to be a string that you are using in division? Are you relying on an implicit conversion? Don't. Declare as the expected type.

For example: `Dim str1() As String, str2 As String, pgno  As Double`

This will also highlight that you have missing variable declarations e.g. `RowCount`.

Comment: QHarr, Thanks for your help, but When I put your code, it does not extract data and explorer exit without any data extraction...Please review the program again. Thanks again

Comment: @shakeelahmad QHarr stated at the beginning that it was not an answer : it was posted so you could review your code and correct / improve it.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks I got it. Now its working fine. Thanks to all.

Comment: I have updated my prior non-answer with an actual answer and moved the comments below to help you review your own code.

Comment: Did this not answer your question? You appear to have used my solution.