# Type Miss Match Error in Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am working on a website data extractor. I have two worksheets one for input and other for output, which looks like this..

[image]

In the first sheet the cell contains the URL needed to extract data. I am trying this URL

https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-sale?limit=30&market=residential&property_type_code%5B%5D=4S&property_type=H&freetext=Yishun

I have written this macro..

```
Sub extractTablesData()
    Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
    Dim str, e As String
    Dim pgf, pgt, pg As Integer
    Dim ele, Results As Object
    Dim add, size, cno, price, inurl, sp, sp1 As String
    Dim isheet, rts As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim pgno As Variant

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set isheet = Worksheets("InputSheet")
    Set rts = Worksheets("Results")

    URL = isheet.Cells(3, 2)

    RowCount = 1
        rts.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Address"
        rts.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Size"
        rts.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Contact Number"
        rts.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Price"
        rts.Range("E" & RowCount) = "Url"
    LastRow = rts.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
      'RowCount = LastRow

     With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate (URL)

        DoEvents
          Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Loop

    'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)

    For Each Results In .document.all
        Select Case Results.className
            Case "title search-title"
                str = Results.innerText
                str1 = Split(str, " ")
                str = CInt(str1(0))
        End Select
        If Results.className = "btn btn-main-inverted dropdown-toggle" And InStr(1, Results.Title, " page") > 2 Then
            str2 = Results.Title
            str1 = Split(str2, " ")
            str2 = CInt(str1(0))
        End If
    Next

    If str2 = 0 Then
        pgno = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
    Else
        pgno = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(str / str2, 0)
    End If
    End With
    IE.Quit

    Set IE = Nothing
    UrlS = Split(URL, "?")
    Url1 = UrlS(0)
    Url2 = "?" & UrlS(1)

    For i = 1 To pgno
      Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      URL = Url1 & "/" & i & Url2
      With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate (URL)

        DoEvents
          Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Loop

        'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:08 AM#)
        For Each ele In .document.all        
          Select Case ele.className
            Case "listing-img-a"
                inurl = ele.href
                rts.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5) = inurl

            Case "listing-location"
                LastRow = LastRow + 1
                add = ele.innerText
                rts.Cells(LastRow, 1) = add

            Case "lst-sizes"
                sp = Split(ele.innerText, " ·")

                size = sp(0)
                rts.Cells(LastRow, 2) = size

            Case "pgicon pgicon-phone js-agent-phone-number"      ' btn-tools" 'pgicon pgicon-phone js-agent-phone-number" 'agent-phone-number"
                rts.Cells(LastRow, 3) = ele.innerText

            Case "listing-price"
                price = ele.innerText
                rts.Cells(LastRow, 4) = price
         End Select        
        Next
    LastRow = rts.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    rts.Activate
    rts.Range("A" & LastRow).Select

    End With
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:04 AM#)
    Next i

    MsgBox "Success"
End Sub
```

When I run this macro I am getting the error

> Type Miss Match

When I debug it highlights the code

```
For i = 1 To pgno 
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") URL = Url1 & "/" & i & Url2 
  With IE .Visible = True .navigate (URL)
```

I have tried my best to figure it out but could not understand where the problem is. Please help me to make correction..

It is also not getting the whole records on the link. This link contains more than 200 Records as per page is 30 records.

Comment: what's the value of `pgno` when hitting error?

Comment: @DisplayName it is not getting any value...

Comment: upom hitting the error, click Debug and once in VBA IDE, open Immediate Window, type `?pgno` and press return

Comment: I think its simple as its declared as variant and not int or long

Comment: @DougCoats, I tried that before, but it worked with `pgno` as a Variant type provided it has a _meaningful_ value

Comment: @DougCoats I also declare it as variant but I getting the same error. as you can please view this code as..

Comment: @DougCoats Please could share that code with me... as I tried it many times but not how I getting it..

Comment: @DisplayName it displaying error 2007

Comment: Is it can be sort out?

Comment: Few things to consider: 1) You have defined it as variant which means you are not sure what will you get in it. 2) You don't have even defined `i`. You must always work with defined variables. 3) Is the server-end programming in your hand? If Yes, then I would suggest you to change server-programming and make it return an `CSV` file and then you can easily open it as `RECORDSET`. Last, Can you share the file with me so that I may sort it out in a better way?

Comment: @HameesA.Khan Please check mail

Comment: Brother, I think your `str2 = 0` is the problem which makes `pgno = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` and obviously, You can't `+1` in 'subtype Error'. CVErr returns Variant on subtype Error. So, stop looking for pgno and start looking for the line where str2 becomes zero. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/cverr-function

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on implicit conversion and use the following. Assuming all pages do have numbering. You might want to improve error handling. I default to page numbers = 1 if the penultimate li CSS selector fails, otherwise it attempts to get the last page number before the `">"`

Refer to my [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51230534/6241235) to your related question which shows you how to more effiently scrape the info off the page.

---

Sample code to show function being used:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetListings()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, pgno As Long
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-sale?limit=30&market=residential&property_type_code%5B%5D=4S&property_type=H&freetext=Yishun", False
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
           pgno  = GetNumberOfPages(.document)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetNumberOfPages(ByVal doc As HTMLDocument) As Long
    On Error GoTo errhand:
    GetNumberOfPages = doc.querySelector(".listing-pagination li:nth-last-child(2)").innerText
    Exit Function
errhand:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then GetNumberOfPages = 1
End Function
```

Comment: The above doesn't work for you? It correctly identifies the page numbering for the example given. Can you provide me with an example where it fails? I will edit it to make it clearer how this is a solution.

Comment: I have edited both answers to hopefully make things clearer.